# Notifying to leave a job during Christmas season in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

I am working in one of UK companies as an employee. I have one and half week holiday during Christmas period, it includes bank holidays and my personal holidays. My notification period is one week as well. Will it will be right to give then notification last working day of the year and, so all following week will be my holiday and bank holidays. Effectively I would not come back to work. Will it be considered proper notification?

Comment: Notification period is a minimum, not a maximum. Why not just notify them now stating your desired leaving date

Comment: Hard to say. They might be able to cancel your holiday and pay you in lieu afterwards. And if you don't turn up fire you. Which they then might mention in a reference legally. Much better to give notice earlier and avoid that kind of trouble.

Comment: then I will get fired just before holidays and won't get paid for the bank holidays.